# Can not fill an array in thread

Tags: java, multithreading, arrays, user-interface, event-listener

This gui should draw moving images on frame panel called "system". But first of all i need to make those objects. Here i'm trying to add them to an array and use that array in other classes. But array keeps being empty!
I guess the problem is in declaring(bottom of the code). There is no exception thrown because I let other classes to execute only when this array(Planetarium) is not empty(it should work like that, because other moves depends on planets created(those objects)). But if it is empty that means nothing is declared...
What should i do if I want to fill an array in the thread executed in event listener?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class GUI extends Frame implements WindowListener,ActionListener {
cpWindow window1 = new cpWindow();
cmWindow window2 = new cmWindow();
Delete window3 = new Delete();
SolarSystem system = new SolarSystem(300,300);
Planet[] Planetarium = null;        // using this to make an array
Moon[] Moonarium = null;
/**
 * Frame for general window.
 */
public void createFrame0(){
JFrame f0 = new JFrame("Choose what you want to do");
f0.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f0.addWindowListener(this);
f0.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
JButton cP = new JButton("Create a planet");
JButton cM = new JButton("Create a moon");
JButton Delete = new JButton("Annihilate a planet or moon");
f0.add(cP);
f0.add(cM);
f0.add(Delete);
cP.addActionListener(this);
cM.addActionListener(this);
Delete.addActionListener(this);
cP.setActionCommand("1");
cM.setActionCommand("2");
Delete.setActionCommand("3");
f0.pack();
f0.setVisible(true);
}
/**
 * Frame for planet adding window.
 */
class cpWindow implements ActionListener,WindowListener{
 JLabel name1  = new JLabel("Name");
 JLabel color1  = new JLabel("Color");
 JLabel diam1  = new JLabel("Diameter");
 JLabel dist1  = new JLabel("Distance");
 JLabel speed1  = new JLabel("Speed");
 JTextField name2 = new JTextField();
 JTextField color2  = new JTextField();
 JTextField diam2  = new JTextField();
 JTextField dist2  = new JTextField();
 JTextField speed2  = new JTextField();
double distance;
int Speed;
double diameter;

public void createFrame1() {
    JFrame f1 = new JFrame("Add planet");
    f1.addWindowListener(this);
    f1.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,2,5,5));
    JButton mygt = new JButton("Create planet");
    mygt.addActionListener(this);
        name2.setText("belekoks");color2.setText("RED");diam2.setText("30");dist2.setText("60");spe    ed2.setText("2");
    f1.add(name1);f1.add(name2);f1.add(color1);f1.add(color2);f1.add(diam1);
    f1.add(diam2);f1.add(dist1);f1.add(dist2);f1.add(speed1);f1.add(speed2);
    f1.add(mygt);   
    f1.pack();
    f1.setVisible(true);
} 
public void createVariables(){
    try {
          distance = Double.parseDouble(dist2.getText());
          Speed = Integer.parseInt(speed2.getText());
          diameter = Double.parseDouble(diam2.getText());
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException i) {
        }
        Main.diametras = diameter;
        Main.distancija = distance;
        Main.greitis = Speed;
        Main.vardas = name2.getText();
        Main.spalva = color2.getText();
        }

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    createVariables();
    new NewThread().start();
            list.display();
}


public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    dispose();
    System.exit(0);
}
public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {}
public void windowActivated(WindowEvent arg0) {}
public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent arg0) {}
public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent arg0) {}
public void windowIconified(WindowEvent arg0) {}
public void windowOpened(WindowEvent arg0) {}
}
/**
 * Frame for moon adding window
 */
CheckboxGroup planets = new CheckboxGroup();
String which;
class cmWindow implements ActionListener,WindowListener, ItemListener{  
 JLabel name1  = new JLabel("Name");
 JLabel color1  = new JLabel("Color");
 JLabel diam1  = new JLabel("Diameter");
 JLabel speed1  = new JLabel("Speed");
 JTextField name2 = new JTextField();
 JTextField color2  = new JTextField();
 JTextField diam2  = new JTextField();
 JTextField speed2  = new JTextField();
 JLabel info  = new JLabel("Which planet's moon it will be?");  
 JLabel corDist1  = new JLabel("Distance from centre of rotation");
 JLabel corSpeed1  = new JLabel("Speed which moon centres");
 JTextField corDist2  = new JTextField();
 JTextField corSpeed2  = new JTextField();

int cordistance;
int corspeed;

public void createFrame1() {
    JFrame f1 = new JFrame("Add moon");
    f1.addWindowListener(this);
    f1.setLayout(new GridLayout(8,2,5,5));
    JButton mygt = new JButton("Create moon");
    mygt.addActionListener(this);
    for(int i=0;i<Planetarium.length;i++){
        add(new Checkbox(Planetarium[i].nam,planets,false));
    }
    corDist2.setText("15");corSpeed2.setText("3");
    f1.add(name1);f1.add(name2);f1.add(color1);f1.add(color2);
    f1.add(diam1);f1.add(diam2);f1.add(speed1);f1.add(speed2);
    f1.add(corDist1);f1.add(corDist2);f1.add(corSpeed1);f1.add(corSpeed2);
    f1.add(mygt);   
    f1.pack();
    f1.setVisible(true);
}
int Speed;
double diameter;
public void createVariables(){
    try {
          Speed = Integer.parseInt(speed2.getText());
          diameter = Double.parseDouble(diam2.getText());
          cordistance = Integer.parseInt(corDist2.getText());
          corspeed = Integer.parseInt(corSpeed2.getText());
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException i) {}
        Main.diametras = diameter;
        Main.greitis = Speed;
        Main.vardas = name2.getText();
        Main.spalva = color2.getText();
        Main.centGrt = corspeed;
        Main.centAts = cordistance;

}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    createVariables();
    new NewThread().start();
}   
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    dispose();
    System.exit(0);
}
public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {}
public void windowActivated(WindowEvent arg0) {}
public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent arg0) {}
public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent arg0) {}
public void windowIconified(WindowEvent arg0) {}
public void windowOpened(WindowEvent arg0) {}
@Override
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
    which = planets.getSelectedCheckbox().getLabel();   
}
}
/**
 * Deleting window
 */
class Delete implements ActionListener,WindowListener{
Checkbox[] checkB = new Checkbox[100];
public void createFrame2(){ 
JFrame f2 = new JFrame("Death Start");
f2.addWindowListener(this);
f2.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,2,5,5));
JButton Del = new JButton("Shoot it!");
Del.addActionListener(this);    
JLabel[] planetName  = new JLabel[100];
    for(int i=0;i<Planetarium.length;i++){
        planetName[i].setText(Planetarium[i].nam);
        checkB[i].setLabel("This");
        checkB[i].setState(false);
        f2.add(planetName[i]);f2.add(checkB[i]);
    }
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    for(int i=0;i<Planetarium.length;i++){
        if(checkB[i].getState()){
            Planetarium[i] = null;
        }
    }
}       

public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    dispose();
    System.exit(0);
}
public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {}
public void windowActivated(WindowEvent arg0) {}
public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent arg0) {}
public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent arg0) {}
public void windowIconified(WindowEvent arg0) {}
public void windowOpened(WindowEvent arg0) {}
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public GUI() {
createFrame0();
}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
if ("1".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {this.window1.createFrame1();}
else if ("2".equals(e.getActionCommand()) & Planetarium != null)     {this.window2.createFrame1();} 
else if ("3".equals(e.getActionCommand()) & Planetarium != null)     {this.window3.createFrame2();}
}

public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
dispose();
System.exit(0);
}
public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {}
public void windowActivated(WindowEvent arg0) {}
public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent arg0) {}
public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent arg0) {}
public void windowIconified(WindowEvent arg0) {}
public void windowOpened(WindowEvent arg0) {}
LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
class NewThread extends Thread {
Thread t;
NewThread() {
  t = new Thread(this);
  t.start(); 
}
public void run() {
    Moon moon = null;
    Planet planet = new     Planet(Main.vardas,Main.distancija,Main.diametras,Main.spalva,Main.greitis);
    if(Planetarium != null){
    for(int i=0;i<Planetarium.length;i++){
        if (which == Planetarium[i].nam){
            moon = new Moon(Main.vardas,Planetarium[i].dist,Main.diametras,Main.spalva,Main.greitis,Main.centGrt,Main.centAts);
        }
    }}
    int a=0,b=0;
    int i = 0;

        if (Main.centAts == 0){
            Planetarium[i] = planet;            //i guess     problem is here
            a++;
                            list.add(planet);
            for(i=0; i <= i+1 0; i++) {
                planet.move();
                planet.drawOn(system);
                system.finishedDrawing();
                                    if (i==360){i=0;}
            }
        }
        else{
            Moonarium[i] = moon;
            b++;
          if(i==Main.greitis){
            for(int l = 0; l <= l+1; l++) {
                moon.move();
                moon.drawOn(system);
                system.finishedDrawing();
            }}
        } 

}
  }
}
```

EDIT: add linkedlist(still nothing after display) and moved declaration before infinite loop

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to have assigned these arrays anything so they should be `null` rather than empty.
The way you are using them a List might be better.

```
final List<Planet> planetarium = new ArrayList<Planet>();

planetarium.add(new Planet( .... ));

Planet p = planetarium.get(i);

for(Planet p: planetarium){
  // something for each planet.
}
```

Note: you have to create an array before using it and you have know its length which is fixed.  A list can have any length, but you still need to create it first.

Comment: first of all, nobody has noticed that i'm trying to do stuff after infinite loop. However I have moved declaration in front of infinite loop AND tried to add object to the linked list, but after trying to display it, nothing happens...

Comment: I would still expect what I suggested to work. I suggest you read my answer again.  What do you see when you try to debug your application?

Comment: yeah, i forgot to mention that i changed array creating condition to, initialized it as null. Still, nothing.

Comment: I updated it:Planet[] Planetarium = null; list is created above the thread, and displayed in cpWindow actionperformed method and array declaration is moved

Comment: * it..I change the code a bit. Now array declaration runs in main cpWIndow class acionperformed() method but it keeps throwing nullpointer exeption at line 92.

Comment: You set Planetarium to be null so it is not surprising you get a NullPointerException when you try to use it.  Why don't you give it a value? When you give it a value, you need to keep track of how many entries you have set to be a planet and how many are still null (unless you know the array will always be populated)  Above all you must be able to run your application in your debugger, in the IDE its the button next to the Run button. ;)  You need this to see what is going on, otherwise you will just be guessing.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the loop before:

```
 Planetarium[i] = planet;
```

It looks like it will loop infinitely

```
for(i=0; i >= 0; i++)
```

`i` will alway be >= 0.

Comment: yeah, it is needed for object moving in the pane =] however that's not related

Comment: @Medardas it is related, because if the code stays in that loop forever it will never get to the next part where it's supposed to add something to Planetarium.